# sql many-to-many query indexes optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a many-to-many query that i'd like to optimize,
what indexes should i create for it?

```
  SELECT (SELECT COUNT(post_id) 
            FROM posts 
           WHERE post_status = 1) as total,
         p.*,
         GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) tagged
    FROM tags_relation tr  
    JOIN posts p ON p.post_id = tr.rel_post_id  
    JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id = tr.rel_tag_id
   WHERE p.post_status=1
GROUP BY p.post_id
```

EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     p   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL        5   Using where; Using filesort
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the query execution plan using the `Explain` statement. This will show you whether a full table scan is happening or if it was able to find an index to retrieve the data. From that point on you can optimize further.

**Edit**

Based on your query execution plan, first optimization step check your tables have the primary key defined and you can set an index on post_status and tag_name columns.

Comment: here is the result

PRIMARY,post_status post_status 1 const 4 Using where; Using filesort

Comment: Now your query has post_status as a key, unlike your previous execution plan which was NULL.

Comment: yea, but i'm still getting "Using where; Using filesort"